# php multiple foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello i am creating a php script in wordpress to generate a dynamic html table which data is fetch from database,

The function is something like this:

1) Theme 
2) Topics
3) items

For each [theme] there are [topics] and for each [topics] there are multiple [items]

I want to display each [topic] As a new row and under which [items] will be displayed

here is my function which is not working help me to correct my code.

```
function dynamic_table($attr) {

global $wpdb;

$ThemeCode = $attr['theme'];
$Themes = getThemeinfo($ThemeCode);
$sr = 1;

$dt_list = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_mtresources WHERE ThemeCode= '$ThemeCode'");
if(!empty($dt_list)) {
    echo '<h2>' . $Themes['Desc'] . '</h2>
        <table style="margin: auto; margin-bottom: 30px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Topic</th>
                <th>Presenation</th>
                <th>Worksheets</th>
                <th>Other Resources</th>
            </tr>
            ';
    foreach ($dt_list as $dt) {
        $tp_list = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_mtresources WHERE TopicCode= '$dt->TopicCode'");

        $Topics = getTopicsinfo($dt->ThemeCode, $dt->TopicCode);    
            echo '  
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center;"><a href=""> ' . $Topics['TopicDesc'] . ' </a></td>
                </tr>';
            foreach ($tp_list as $tp) {

                echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td>' . $tp->ResourceLocation.'</td>    
                        <td></td>   
                        <td></td>   
                        <td></td>   
                    </tr>       
                ';

            }
    }   
        echo '</tbody>
              </table>';    
} else {
    return 'No Theme or Topic found.';
}   


 }
 add_shortcode('dt', 'dynamic_table');
```

And here is unexpected result 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGR1Z.jpg)

Comment: Not a solution for your specific problem, but you should never do SQL selects in a loop. Better first get  all data you need and loop over objects or arrays.

Comment: what you expect ? not working doesn't help us to debug your problem

Comment: Can you guide me how can i do that ? any small example will be a great help for me

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: tell us what is your expected output ?

Comment: Expected output
http://jsfiddle.net/YzSak/

Comment: what is var_dump($dt_list) ? are you getting unique topics in $dt_list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I would select from your database

```
PDO example..
while($rows = $query->fetch(PDO:FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $data = $rows;
}
```

Now everything is in the $data array with your table names as key.

hold any other data in other arrays

`$another_array = ['example', 'example'];`  <- just an example could be another database retrieval like above, whatever just another array of data!

Then for each loop the one of the arrays but access other arrays within that loop..

```
$array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
$array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

foreach($array1 as $k => $v){
     echo $v.' - '.$array2[$k];
}
```

Result will look like..

> one - a 
>   two - b 
>   three - c

Sorry if this is not clear enough!

Answer (score 0):

in one of my instance i did like this

```
$i=0;
$count=10;
echo count($_POST['dates']);echo'<br>';
while($i<10 )
{
$date = ($_POST['dates'][$i]) ;
$fee = ($_POST['fee'][$i]);
echo "The value of  is".$date .'-------'.$fee;
echo'<br>';
$i=$i+1;
} 

and it gave answer like 
The value of is2017-02-28-------800
The value of is2017-02-21-------1000
The value of is2017-02-13-------200
```

Comment: here i knew max size was 10 in objects